# Maximum and minimum of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Tags: maxima-minima

Is there a way how to calculate maximum and minumum of

$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

without taking the derivative of it?

Comment: Have you tried drawing the graph $y=f(x)$?

Comment: yeah, I'm sorry, I wanted to know if we can find out the max and min without the graph.

Comment: It is decreasing on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @abc Welcome to Math SE. Note you asked the same question as your original update part (which you have now removed), at [maximum and minimum of $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3629145/602049) about $40$ minutes later, with it currently having $1$ answer. In the future, instead of adding a new question to an old one as an update, please just directly ask a new question. I'm glad to see you recognize this in your comment on the other question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I wont do that again. I marked one of the answers as accepted, because it solved the problem with one in numerador, so I wanted to separete them as they are different when it comes to ways how to solve them. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$0 \le x^2< \infty$$

$$1 \le 1+x^2< \infty$$

$$1 \ge \frac {1}{1+x^2}>0$$

Comment: thanks! and if we have in the numerator x? $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$

Comment: Then consider $x+\frac {1}{x}$ Consider two seperate cases x<0 and x>0. Use AM, GM inequality

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about this:

When is a fraction $\frac{1}{A}$ the maximum? --> When A is the smallest.

When is a fraction $\frac{1}{A}$ the minimum? --> When A is the largest.

The minimal value for $1 + x^2$ is $1$ because $x^2$ is non-negative. So the minimum of $x^2$ is $0$ which leads to $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + 0} = 1$. Therefore at $x = 0$ is the maximum of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

However you can make $1+x^2$ as large as you want by enlarging $x$. So there is no largest number for $1 + x^2$ and therefore the minimum is in the limit approaching $0$ at $\pm \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum of your function corresponds to the minimum of $1 + x^2$ and similarly for the minimum.

So you know that $x^2+1$ is a parabola and we know that min/max of a parabola $ax^2 + bx + c$ is at $\frac{-b}{2a}$. It can be shown without a derivative by representing it in the form $a(x-\lambda)^2 + \beta$.

Answer (score 0):

For $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$,

Note that $0\le x^2<\infty$

Adding $1$ across the board,

$1\le 1+x^2 < \infty$

Taking the reciprocal,

$1 \ge \frac{1}{1+x^2} > 0$

---

For $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ where $x>0$

Divide both numerator and denominator by $x$,

So, $f(x)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+x}$,

Note that the denominator can be rewritten as

$(\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+2)-2=(\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})^2-2$.

Clearly, $(\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})^2-2 \ge -2$ or $(\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})^2 \ge 0$ or $x+\frac{1}{x}+2 \ge 0$

This means, $x+\frac{1}{x} \ge 2$ or $x+\frac{1}{x} \le -2$

The equality holds true (for max. and min.) leading us to:

- Max is $1$ by setting $x=1$.
- Min is $-$ by setting $x=-1$.

---

**While answering this problem, the original post has been edited where this part was removed, hope you make your question clear as much as possible before posting, thanks, hope my answer helps.**