# maximum and minimum of $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$

Tags: maxima-minima

Is there a way how to calculate maximum and minumum of

$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$

without derivative?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note you asked basically the same question at [Maximum and minimum of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3629091/602049) about $40$ minutes ago, with it currently having $3$ answers. Please don't do that as it causes unnecessary duplication and waste of member's time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum and minimum of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3629091/maximum-and-minimum-of-fx-frac11x2)

Comment: To be fair, it is not the _exact_ same question

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, but this question is quite different as we have x in the numerador, so this problem is not that easy to solve as the one asked earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$y=\frac{x}{1+x^2},$$ where $x$ is real. Then writing as a quadratic in $x$ gives $$yx^2-x+y=0,$$ whose discriminant $(-1)^2-4y^2$ must not be negative. Hence we find that $$1-4y^2\ge 0.$$ This tells us that $$|y|\le\frac12,$$ or in other words that $$-\frac12\le y\le \frac12.$$

These bounds will clearly be attained since then our quadratic will have real roots for $x.$ Thus, these are the extreme values of the function.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{2} + 1}{2} \geq \sqrt{x^{2}} = |x| \Longrightarrow \left|\frac{x}{1+x^{2}}\right| \leq \frac{1}{2} \Longrightarrow -\frac{1}{2}\leq\frac{x}{1+x^{2}}\leq\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

First, this function is odd. So it is enough to find its bounds on $\mathbf R_{\ge 0}$.

You can rewrite this function, for $x\ne 0$,  as
$$\frac x{1+x^2}= \frac 1{x+\dfrac 1x}.$$

Now it is  standard that, for $x>0$, $x+\dfrac1x \ge 2$ (it is a direct consequence of the AGM inequality) and the minimum is attained when $x=\frac 1x$, i.e. $x=1$.

Therefore, if $x\ge 0$, we have
$$0\le\frac x{1+x^2} \le \frac12,$$By symmetry, if $x\le 0$,we have
$$-\frac12\le \frac x{1+x^2} \le 0,$$
from which you obtain instantly the bounds, attained at $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>0$,

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}=\frac1{(\sqrt x-\frac1{\sqrt x} )^2 +2 }\le \frac12 $$

Given that $f(x)$ is odd, we have

$$-\frac12 \le f(x)\le \frac12 $$